# Getting plperl to work on 9.3 in OSX

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm attempting to install plperl on Postgres 9.3 package I downloaded from Enterprise DB on OSX Mavericks. -- Every time I issue

```
create language plperl
```

I get

```
postgres-# ;
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
!>
```

Edit: The log file shows

```
2014-01-02 14:08:50 CST LOG:  server process (PID 4843) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
2014-01-02 14:08:50 CST DETAIL:  Failed process was running: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plperl WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;
2014-01-02 14:08:50 CST LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2014-01-02 14:08:50 CST WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2014-01-02 14:08:50 CST DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2014-01-02 14:08:50 CST HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2014-01-02 14:08:50 CST WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2014-01-02 14:08:50 CST DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2014-01-02 14:08:50 CST HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
```

I vaguely recall having to mess around with activeperl libraries to get it installed on  9.2, but I  thought perhaps someone on here knew the best way to get plperl up and running on OSX.

It's sad, but I really don't need plperl except that perl has the best implementation of a sprintf function (that uses some of the more advanced formatting options), but I digress.

Comment: Isn't there anything in the server logs?

Comment: +1 (It's dark, and we're wearing sunglasses ...) Do other commands work correctly ?

Comment: see my edits, I added the log entries. queries and such that don't use the pl/perl language seem to be working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

To install plperl, you must install plperl 5.14, that version,no higher or lower.
Activestate has made this difficult in that they've changed up all their licensing and you now must pay for access to this older version (and it's the last version that postgres can use license free). Luckily, even though they've scrubbed 5.14 from their download site, CNET still has it available. It can be downloaded here:

[ActivePerl 5.14 OSX /x86](http://download.cnet.com/ActivePerl-Mac/3000-2069_4-75211978.html)